# Bundled scripts/css are not being recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I am very new to Bundling and minification, I try to implement it for the first time in my MVC project.

I have added a BundleConfig.cs file:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        //libs scripts
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        "~/Scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/libs/jquery/jquery.mask*",
        "~/Scripts/libs/jquery/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ko").Include(
        "~/Scripts/libs/ko/knockout-{version}.js"));

        //site scripts
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/site").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/site/*.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/site/").Include("~/Content/site/*.css"));
    }
}
```

And added in Global.asax:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Then I rendered the scripts/css in my Layout page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/site/Fonts.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/site/Site.css")
    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ko")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

But this is not working, I keep getting all kind of errors that indicate that the scripts and css are not being recognized.

For example:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't add the files manually and using the bundles - delete all your `<script src="...` code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, I don't have both, I copied it like this by mistake...

Comment: Are you duplicating any of those in the main view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no, I double check.

Comment: Have you checked the sources tab in the browser tools to see if they are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @BasantaMatia comment that gave me the idea, setting:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true
```

In the Global.asax file, after:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See here you are adding 2 times all the scripts files,

You already added reference your bundle jquery, ko and site.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ko")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
```

Then there is no need to add again these files.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Libs/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Libs/jquery-mask/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Libs/knockout/knockout-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Site/Site.js"></script>
```

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Can you add this line "BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;" after RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) method in BundleConfig file and check